# Soundcloud repost by api

Tags: api, soundcloud

I was using soundcloud to repost tracks by this api endpoint:

api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/track_reposts

But it stopped to work. Does someone have more information about it? Is there anyway to repost a track by API?

Answer (score 1):

I can still get reposted tracks by a user with this:

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/profile/soundcloud:users:{user}?client_id=2bdf.....

Answer (score 0):

The documented SoundCloud API doesn't include reposts:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

This is by design. Reposts are not a part of the product that SoundCloud makes available to API users. The endpoint you are using was originally built for internal apps, but is now being retired. As of this writing, it is still available in a read-only form, but that will likely go away soon as well.

Generally we suggest the widget or embed for things not available in the public API. Unfortunately, it doesn't contain repost capability either. What are you using reposts for? I *might* be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Dave, I use repost for Download Gateways, also Soundcloud did not removed it, because in other websites the repost still working.

Comment: Also, why "api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/reposts/" returns "500 - Internal Server Error"? It means it still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Used it for download gates. Was working a few weeks ago, no problem, now I got 404 Not Found as a result.

http://taffo.tunevoyage.com/hybrid_x_dubstep

The Artist Union and ToneDen are still reposting tracks, no problem. Have no idea what they are using for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an old SDK it actually makes a POST request to `api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/track_reposts`, the method should be PUT, otherwise it will return a 404 error. So if you look at the network monitor `SC.put('api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/track_reposts/{track_id}');`, it does a POST. I am still using the old SDK, but I just made a new function with PUT. Now it works alright.